# Importing a .CSV using SqlBulkCopy With ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, sqlbulkcopy

Hi I am trying to migrate some projects to ASP.Net Core and having some issues with what is the correct way to upload a .CSV file to my SQL database.

In the past I would upload the .CSV file loop through it and store that information in a DataTable and then simply do a SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer but I have found out that currently there is not a DataTable object in .Net Core.  SQLBulkCopy accepts a DbDataReader instead of a DataTable.

What is the best method to get this to work.  I have the file uploaded and I can work with the contents I just need to get the data in the proper format to do an upload to my SQL database.

Open to any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it using [FastMember's](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) objectreader and and a columnmapping like this:

```cs
 List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();
        //fill list of data..

        using (var sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Config.get("Data:db:ConnectionString")))
        {
            sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = "[tblBulkCopy]";
            sqlCopy.BatchSize = 500;

            //map property index to column index in table. in database table the first column is the identitycolumn
            sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1);
            sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2);
            sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3);

            var records = lstData.Select(obj => new { col1 = obj.number1, col2 = obj.number2, col3 = obj.number3 });

            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(records, new[] { "col1", "col2", "col3" }))
            {
                sqlCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `//map property index to column index in table. in database table the first column is the identitycolumn` That bit saved me too much trouble. Thanks for taking the time to post your findnigs